# Exact sum rule for solutions of the transcendental equation $x \tan x=\xi$

Tags: sequences-and-series, transcendental-equations

Consider the transcendental equation
\begin{equation}
x_j \tan x_j=\xi
\end{equation}
with $\xi$ real and positive and with $j=0,1,2,\dots$.
The roots lie approximately at
\begin{equation}
    x_j \approx \begin{cases}
         &\sqrt{\frac{\xi}{3+\xi}}, \quad j=0\,\newline
         & \pi j + \frac{\xi}{\pi j}, \quad j=1,2,\dots
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}
see Eq. (13) of [this article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2103.16914.pdf).
For $\xi\leq 1$, the error of this approximation is less then $1\%$.
The error increases as $\xi$ becomes larger.

I believe$^{1,2}$ that the roots satisfy the *exact* sum rule
\begin{equation}
     \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin^2 x_j}{\xi + \sin^2 x_j} =\frac{1}{2}.
\end{equation}
My question is whether there is a *direct* route (as opposed to footnote 1) to prove this sum rule.
**Are there other examples of solutions to transcendental equations satisfying exact sum rules?**

$^1$ The above sum rule follows from the high frequency ($\omega\to\infty$) limit of the impedance of the so-called transmission line model, see [this article](https://journals.aps.org/prxenergy/abstract/10.1103/PRXEnergy.2.043006).
That article shows numerically in Fig. 10 that (I dropped some unimportant factors)
\begin{equation}
    Z(i\omega)=\left( \sum_{j\ge0}\frac{4 x_j \sin^2 x_j}{2x_j +\sin 2 x_j} \frac{i \omega }{x_j^2 +i \omega }\right)^{-1}
\end{equation}
is identical to
\begin{equation}
    Z(i\omega)=\frac{1}{\xi}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{i \omega} } \coth \sqrt{ i \omega }
\end{equation}
For the case $\xi\to\infty$, the equivalence of the two $Z(i\omega)$ expressions can be shown analytically, see Eqs. (61)-(64) of the mentioned article.
I would be interested to see a proof for the equivalence of two $Z(i\omega)$ expressions for arbitrary $\xi$.

$^2$ The script below supports this conjecture.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize

def transcendental_eq(x, xi):
    return x*np.sin(x)-xi*np.cos(x)

def x_sol(xi):
    return [optimize.newton(transcendental_eq,i, args=(xi,)) for i in x0]

ml=1000 #sum range 
x0= np.concatenate(([np.pi/2], [np.pi*i+np.pi/4 for i in range(1,ml)]))#guess for solution

def sumrule(xi):
    x = x_sol(xi)
    s=0
    for i in range(0,ml):
        s+=np.sin(x[i])**2/(xi+np.sin(x[i])**2)
    return s    

print(sumrule(0.1))
print(sumrule(1))
print(sumrule(10))
```

Output:

0.4999898628139413

0.4998986281525962

0.49898628584402044